# Wrong POST data in production

Tags: symfony, nginx, php

I'am facing very strange problem in production server. I'm developing MLM project where users can order products from their personal cabinet. The problem is appearing when they refresh(change the quantity of the selected items) on cart page, if user changes the quantity and refresh the cart price is being calculated incorrectly, however everything is working properly in my local machine:

Here is a simplified version of code:

QuantityType

```
....
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $productLineItems = $options['productLineItems'];

    /** @var ProductLineItem $productLineItem */
    foreach ($productLineItems as $productLineItem) {
        $builder
            ->add(
                $builder
                    ->create($productLineItem->getId(), 'form', [
                        'data' => $productLineItem
                    ])
                    ->add('quantity', 'number', [
                        'data' => $productLineItem->getQuantity()
                    ])
                    ->add('remove', 'submit')
            );
    }
}
```

CartType

```
...
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('productLineItems', 'sl_core_quantity', [
            'productLineItems' => $options['productLineItems']
        ])
        ->add('update', 'submit')
    ;

    ...
}
```

Controller:

```
$partner = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('SLCoreBundle:User')->find($partnerId);

/** @var BaseOrderManager $orderManager */
$orderManager = $this->get('sl.core.manager.base_order');

$order = $orderManager->getOrderByUserAndStatus($partner, BaseOrder::STATUS_CART, BaseOrderManager::TYPE_PARTNER);

$cartProductLineItems = $orderManager->getProductLineItemsByOrder($order);

$cartForm = null;
if (null != $cartProductLineItems) {
    $cartForm = $this->createForm('sl_core_cart', null, [
        'productLineItems' => $cartProductLineItems,
        'user' => $partner,
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('ACTION', ['partnerId' => $partnerId])
    ]);

    $cartForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($cartForm->isValid()) {

        $clickedButton = $cartForm->getClickedButton();

        if ($clickedButton->getName() == 'remove') {
            $selectedItem = $clickedButton->getParent()->getData();

            $label = $selectedItem->getLabel();

            $orderManager->removeItemFromOrder($order, $selectedItem);

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', $label . ' removed from your cart.');
        }
        else if ($clickedButton->getName() == 'update') {
            $submittedData = $cartForm->getData();

            $submittedProductLineItems = $submittedData['productLineItems'];

            $orderManager->updateProductLineItems($order, $submittedProductLineItems);

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Shopping cart updated.');
        }
        else if ($clickedButton->getName() == 'checkout') {
            $submittedData = $cartForm->getData();
            $submittedProductLineItems = $submittedData['productLineItems'];
            $orderManager->updateProductLineItems($order, $submittedProductLineItems);

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ACTION', ['partnerId' => $partnerId]));
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ACTOPN', ['partnerId' => $partnerId]));
    }
}

return $this->render('@SLWeb/BackOffice/Order/create_partner_order.cart.html.twig', [
    'currency_code' => $request->cookies->get('sl_currency_code'),
    'cart_form' => null != $cartForm ? $cartForm->createView() : null,
    'cart_product_line_items' => $cartProductLineItems,
    'order' => $order,
    'partner' => $partner
]);
```

BaseOrderManager

```
public function updateProductLineItems(BaseOrder $order, array $lineItems)
    {
        $quantityChanged = false;

        $orderLineItems = $this->entityManager->getRepository('SLCoreBundle:ProductLineItem')->fetchAllUnchangedQuantityByOrder($order);

        /**
         * @var int $key
         * @var ProductLineItem $submittedLineItem
         */
        foreach (array_values($lineItems) as $key => $submittedLineItem) {

            $submittedLineItemQuantity = $submittedLineItem->getQuantity();
            $orderLineItemQuantity = $orderLineItems[$key]['quantity'];

            if ($submittedLineItemQuantity == $orderLineItemQuantity) {
                continue;
            }

            ....

            $productLineItemPrices = $submittedLineItem->getLineItemPrices();
            /** @var LineItemPrice $productLineItemPrice */
            foreach ($productLineItemPrices as $productLineItemPrice) {
                $priceValue = $productLineItemPrice->getValue();

                $productLineItemPrice->setTotalPrice($priceValue * $submittedLineItem->getQuantity());

                if ($submittedLineItemQuantity < $orderLineItemQuantity) {
                    $quantityDiff = $orderLineItemQuantity - $submittedLineItemQuantity;
                    $this->updateOrderPrice($order, $productLineItemPrice, $quantityDiff, self::QUANTITY_DECREASED);

                    ....
                }
                else {
                    $quantityDiff = $submittedLineItemQuantity - $orderLineItemQuantity;
                    $this->updateOrderPrice($order, $productLineItemPrice, $quantityDiff, self::QUANTITY_INCREASED);

                    ....
                }
            }

            $quantityChanged = true;
        }

        if ($quantityChanged) {
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
    }



public function updateOrderPrice(BaseOrder $order, LineItemPrice $lineItemPrice, $quantity, $operation = self::QUANTITY_INCREASED)
    {
        $priceCurrency = $lineItemPrice->getCurrencyCode();
        $priceValue = $lineItemPrice->getValue();

        $orderPrice = $this->getPriceByCurrencyCode($order, $priceCurrency);
        $orderPriceValue = $orderPrice->getValue();

        ...

        if ($operation == self::QUANTITY_INCREASED) {
            $orderPrice->setValue($orderPriceValue + ($quantity * $priceValue));
        }
        else if ($operation == self::QUANTITY_DECREASED) {
            $orderPrice->setValue($orderPriceValue - ($quantity * $priceValue));
        }
        else {
            throw new \Exception();
        }
    }
```

production server screen (wrong):
[image]
even worse (after the next refresh)

[image]

local version (correct):
[image]

I can't even understand why the same version of code is working so differently, project versions are the same, php, nginx, mysql versions and configurations are the same, disableing caching doesn't help, Where to dig?

Comment: Have you checked architecture? 32bit vs 64bit (although from what I see, those integers aren't large enough). Otherwise, try posting some code.

Comment: @HalfCrazed 32bit for both systems..

Comment: can't fix invisible code

Comment: @Dagon Ok, I posted some code

Answer (score 0):

May be I somehow solved the problem, but I didn't understand the problem and the solution completely :)

In my `fetchAllUnchangedQuantityByOrder($order)` method I was doing direct query to the database to fetch unchanged rows, like this (because, my getters were returning the changed form values after form binding):

```
public function fetchAllUnchangedQuantityByOrder(BaseOrder $order)
{
    $orderId = $order->getId();

    $connection = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare('
        SELECT li.quantity
        FROM sl_product_line_item AS li
        INNER JOIN
        sl_base_line_item AS bli ON li.id = bli.id
        WHERE bli.order_id = :order_id
        ORDER BY bli.created_at ASC
    ');

    $connection->bindParam(':order_id', $orderId, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $connection->execute();

    return $connection->fetchAll();
}
```

I think this was the issue, sometimes it was returning wrong value, I didn't understand why..

I changed that line to this and problem disappeared..

```
...

$orderLineItem = $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($submittedLineItem);

if ($submittedLineItemQuantity == $orderLineItem['quantity']) {
    continue;
}

...
```